# Hollyhock deteriorating immediately after blooming

Tags: flowers, growth, fungus, flowering, sunlight

I live in Denver, CO and last year I planted 2 Hollyhock plants in my backyard.  The plants were about 1 foot tall when I put them in the ground and they are in a spot where they get full sun/plenty of water.  Unfortunately I lost one of them over the winter but the other survived and thrived.  It began to grow at a rapid rate in the Spring and then finally began to bloom.  However over the course of 7 days it began to deteriorate rapidly.  Leaves yellowing/falling off, the blooms started to shrivel up and die.  This particular Hollyhock is supposed to have pink flowers and it appears that it just got to that point, then died.  I actually removed most of the dead leaves/flowers and sprayed with fungicide because I noticed black spots all over the blooms.  Does anyone have any idea what could have happened?  Is there a way to save the plant?  I'm so disappointed that it got so close to being amazing and then died for no apparent reason.  [image]